# Does anyone know about the DIDEA brand camera tripod?

Tags: accessories

I am searching for a tripod for my 60D. I have not heard of The DIDEA brand before. One thing attracts me, their data shows 20KG for loading, even though it is a small tripod. I wonder if anyone who has used it, and how does it rate?

Comment: I've never heard of them either. They appear to be a relatively new Chinese company. They look reasonably well made in photos but that of course means nothing.

Comment: They look like Benro clones to me. Probably from the same factory. If a weight capacity number sounds too good to be true, it is. I would look elsewhere for a reputable manufacturer with realistic specs.

Answer (score 2):

[DIDEA](http://www.gzdidea.com/) appears to be a small Chinese camera accessory company.  According to information found on Google they are relatively new, having incorporated in 2010, roughly with an annual revenue in the $100k-$500k range, and approximately 11-50 employees ([reference](http://dideatripod.en.ec21.com/company_info.jsp)).  Some other sites slightly vary that information, but it gives you a good idea of how big they are.

I wouldn't expect much in terms of warranty, support, or service, but you might be able to get a good deal on a decent tripod, monopod or head.  Given their small size and lack of presence in the market, it will be extremely difficult to ascertain quality unless someone has first-hand experience with them.

This is a gamble that might be worthwhile if the price sounds good to you.  Good luck!